# SqlDependency isn't firing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

SqlDependency isn't firing. This is something that worked in the past so I don't know what went wrong.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency;
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=SqlServerTestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FullName, State FROM [Sales].[Customer]", connection))
            {
                dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success!!!!");
                });
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read()) { } //NoOP
                }
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for event. dependency.HasChanges = {dependency.HasChanges}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

SQL to trigger event:

```
INSERT INTO Sales.Customer(FullName, State ) VALUES ( N'Test 123', 'CA');
```

I'm not getting an error, the event is simply not firing.

The user is `sysadmin` and the service broker is enabled at the database level.

Database version: 14.0.2002.14

Comment: Try running a SQL trace to capture the requests.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but I was seeing the temporary SPs being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for you to be database owner and still have your account's security settings screwed up. To fix this, delete the user (not the login), then recreate it.